# Perform multi-language search sitecore

Tags: content-search

I have small issue with search results where its showing duplicate items because it has different version created and sometimes it only shows default language version.

The code i have is as per below,

Below method returns IQueryable<>

```
return context.GetQueryable<SearchResult>().Where(item => item["Enable"] = "1");
```

After I get the results I can see different version of each item, later on i do filtering/sorting as per below,

```
results.AddRange(query.Where(item => item.Title.Equals("keywordinput"))
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.SortOrder)
    .ThenBy(item => item.DateTime));
```

Soon as i use the linq, it's only showing default language not based on context language. I've tried applying language when running `GetQueryable<>` but then I only get item that has language but I would also like to display other items  that don't have language i.e. the default language.

Is there a way I can do this?  for example suppose i have

Item1 has two version en and us

Item2 has only one version en

So if someone search "item" then im expecting two results to be displayed

Item1 - us version

Item2 - en version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your solution relies on Sitecore’s content search and you want to use language fallback, you must set up the particular search index to handle item- or field-level fallback. You'll want to patch in the config updates to each index you need the functionality for then perform a full rebuild.

```
<index id="sitecore_master_index" …>
…
   <enableItemLanguageFallback>true</enableItemLanguageFallback>
   <enableFieldLanguageFallback>true</enableFieldLanguageFallback>
…
</index>
```

For more information you can read the Sitecore documentation https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/language_fallback/setting_up/configure_language_fallback for the feature.

Answer (score 0):

### Languages

You can modify your query adding a language parameter:

```
// This can be also defined somewhere in config, etc.
var defaultLang = "en"

var contextLang = Sitecore.Context.Language != null ? 
        Sitecore.Context.Language.Name : DefaultLanguageName;

query.Where(item => item.Title.Equals("keywordinput") 
        && (item.Language == contextLang || item.Language == defaultLang));
...
```

You can also use the predicate builder to make sure the queries are more readable.

---

### Versions

In order to achieve that you can use the inbound/outbound filter.

Please, refer to the [doc](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecore_7_development_team/posts/sitecore-7-inbound-and-outbound-filter-pipelines)

If that doesn't help, you can define a new field on the indexable:

```
[IndexField(“_latestversion”)]
public bool IsLatestVersion { get; set; }
```

And then use the following condition in your query:

```
.Where(item => item.IsLatestVersion)
```

Comment: Thanks, i've tried this but its giving same results apparently